How to evaluate $ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \ln^n\left(\frac{1}{1+xyz}+\frac{1}{1-xyz}\right) \, dx \, dy \, dz. $?

Question and some background

I was evaluating the integral
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \ln\left(\frac{1}{1+xyz}+\frac{1}{1-xyz}\right) \, dx \, dy \, dz,
$$
and while working on it, I got the idea to generalize it to
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \ln^n\left(\frac{1}{1+xyz}+\frac{1}{1-xyz}\right) \, dx \, dy \, dz.
$$
Is it possible to find a closed form for the general term $n$?
For $n=2$, I derived the closed form:
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \ln^2\left(\frac{1}{1 + xyz} + \frac{1}{1 - xyz}\right) \, dx \, dy \, dz = \ln^2(2) + \frac{\pi^2 + 7\zeta(3) - 24}{2}\ln 2 - \frac{\pi^4}{16} - \frac{7\pi^2}{3} - 14\zeta(3) + 48.
$$
I have also attached my solution for the $n=1$ case.

Approach for n=1

$$
\Omega = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \ln\left(\frac{1}{1+xyz}+\frac{1}{1-xyz}\right) dxdydz
$$
$$
\Omega = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \ln^2(x)\ln\left(\frac{1}{1+x} + \frac{1}{1-x}\right)dx
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{2} \ln(2) \int_0^1 \ln^2(x)dx - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \ln^2(x)\ln(1-x^2)dx.
$$
$$
\int_0^1 \ln^2(x)\ln(1-x^2)dx = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \int_0^1 x^{2n}\ln^2(x)dx
$$
$$
= -2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{(2n+1)^3}
$$
$$
= 4\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(2n+1)^3} + \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}\right) + 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{2n+1} - \frac{2}{2n}\right)
$$
$$
= 4\left(\frac{7\zeta(3)}{8} - 1 + \frac{\pi^2}{8} - 1\right) + 2(2\ln(2) - 2)
$$
$$
= \frac{7\zeta(3)}{2} - 8 + \frac{\pi^2}{2} + 4\ln(2) - 4
$$
$$
= \frac{7\zeta(3)}{2} + \frac{\pi^2}{2} + 4\ln(2) - 12.
$$
$$
\Omega = \ln(2) \left(2\ln(2) - 1\right) + \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{7\zeta(3)}{2} + \frac{\pi^2}{2} + 4\ln(2) - 12\right)
$$
$$
= \frac{7\zeta(3)}{4} - \frac{\pi^2}{4} - \ln(2) + 6
$$

I suppose a typo on the last line. If I am not wrong, it should be $$\Omega={\color{red}{-}} \frac{7\zeta(3)}{4} - \frac{\pi^2}{4} - \ln(2) + 6$$

\begin{align}J_n&=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \ln^n\left(\frac{1}{1+xyz}+\frac{1}{1-xyz}\right) \, dx \, dy \, dz\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\ln^n\left(\frac{2}{1-x^2y^2z^2}\right)dxdydz\\
&\overset{u(z)=xyz}=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac1{xy}\left(\int_0^{xy}\ln^n\left(\frac{2}{1-u^2}\right)\right)dxdy\\
&=\overset{v(y)=xy}=\int_0^1\frac1x\left(\int_0^x\frac1v\left(\int_0^v\ln^n\left(\frac{2}{1-u^2}\right)du\right)dv\right)dx\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=\int_0^1\frac1x\left(\ln x\left(\int_0^x\ln^n\left(\frac{2}{1-u^2}\right)du\right)-\int_0^x\ln v\ln^n\left(\frac{2}{1-v^2}\right)dv\right)dx\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=-\frac12\int_0^1\ln^2x\ln^n\left(\frac{2}{1-x^2}\right)dx+\int_0^1\ln^2x\ln^n\left(\frac{2}{1-x^2}\right)dx\\
&=\boxed{\frac12\int_0^1\ln^2x\ln^n\left(\frac{2}{1-x^2}\right)dx}\\
&\overset{w=x^2}=\frac1{16}\int_0^1w^{-\frac12}\ln^n\left(\frac{2}{1-w}\right)\ln^2wdw\\
&=\frac1{16}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\ln^{n-k}2\int_0^1w^{-\frac12}\ln^k(1-w)\ln^2wdw\\
&=\frac1{16}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\ln^{n-k}2\left.\frac{d^{k+2}}{ds^kdt^2}\int_0^1(1-w)^{s+1-1}w^{\frac12+t-1}dw\right|_{s=0,t=0}\\
&=\boxed{\frac1{16}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\ln^{n-k}2\left.\frac{d^{k+2}}{ds^kdt^2}\text{B}\left(s+1,\frac12+t\right)\right|_{s=0,t=0}}\\
\end{align}
